# get error field is required when #access is false with field permission  in image field 

Tags: 7, forms

With `fieldpermission` module I set some permission on some fields(fields are in profile type (I used `profile2` module)) ,some of them are `required` , showing of field is ok ,(they are not showend and `#access` property of them is `false` ). but when I save node  get `field is required` error to me. 
any idea?

**update:** after some debugging find out this problem not issued from profile2 module, problem is a bug(maybe) with `image` cck field and `field permission`. when you have image cck field and restrict it with field permission even it not showed(by `#access=false` ) but in submit (if it `reqired`) , return  the image field name is required.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fieldpermission bug with image and file cck field.

You can get all element in `form_alter` and if `#access` set `false` remove `#require` of it

```
    if ($profile_type == 'profile_main') {
    foreach($form[$profile_type] as $index=>$value) {
          if (preg_match('/^field_/', $index)){
                if ($form[$profile_type][$index]['#access'] == FALSE)  
                  $form[$profile_type][$index]['und'][0]['#required']=FALSE;
          }
        }
    }
```